# Check image exists on server

Tags: javascript

When I use this function for verify is image upload on server, safari debugger shows error

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    send ([native code], line 0)
    UrlExists (myfunction.js, line 32)
    (anonymous function) (user_dialog_list.php, line 354)
    c (jquery.js, line 4)
    fireWith (jquery.js, line 4)
    k (jquery.js, line 6)
    r (jquery.js, line 6)
```

What this mean, and this is normal or not?

Comment: A 404 error is what you get from a server when what you requested doesn't exist. That's a bad way to do things, however, because it requires that the browser wait for each HTTP request to complete. It'll make your page(s) extremely sluggish.

Comment: I understand that if this is normal or is there another way to check images on server!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why would the images not exist? The situation seems pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create a `new Image()`, set its `src` to the target image, and set an `onload` handler to do something if it does exist, as well as an `onerror` handler to do something if it doesn't.

You will still get the `404` error in your console, but that's fine - we're handling the error because we expect errors may happen!